# Ubuntu 16.04.1 Released: Do I have to upgrade my system and if so how?

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, updates

There are many questions with answers on Ask Ubuntu about upgrading, for example, from 14.04 to 16.04. (Between LTS versions.) I recently heard that 16.04.1 has been released.

Do I have to do anything more than `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` to update my system to 16.04.1?

A simple question which requires little explanation! Hopefully also a simple answer?

Note: I have 16.04 currently!

Note: The linked question does not explain how to upgrade from 16.04 to 16.04.1. (For example.) However it does cover upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04. (For example.) Is the method the same? (The answer posted below and in the comments suggests no.)

Comment: Before you do anything else, you should backup your current system.

Comment: It's only got steam on it I wouldn't worry

Comment: I don't think this answers the specific case of sub releases? (16.04 -> 16.04.1)

Comment: Ubuntu will prompt you whenever it thinks it is appropriate to update. Will most likely show up soon.

Comment: No. The commands you state in your question will bring you up to date for point releases.

Comment: @ElderGeek What commands should I have run?

Comment: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` as you stated in your question....

Comment: @ElderGeek Thanks - sorry I interpreted what you said as "No" - as I wasn't sure what a "point release" was. I assume it means A release such as 16.04.1? In which case why do ubuntu bother releasing a new iso image 16.04.1? Is it just to save everyone from updating their systems in future?

Comment: Consider how helpful having a new ISO could be to someone setting up a new system without the ability to connect to the Internet to pull down all the updates. You are correct in that a point release has a number after the second point such as 12.04.5 14.04.2 or in this case 16.04.1

Comment: @ElderGeek I guess it would be convenient - and useful if those contained major security updates, for example.

Answer (score 6):

To upgrade from 16.04 to 16.04.1:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

To upgrade from 14.04.x to 16.04.1:

Step 1: Back up your current system. "Dirty" upgrades from one release to another don't always go as planned, so you should make sure that you've backed up any data you don't want to lose.

Step 2: Update your current system with `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Step 3: Make sure you have the update-manager-core package installed: `sudo apt install update-manager-core`

Step 4: Upgrade to the current release: `sudo do-release-upgrade`

[Source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

All that being said, I would recommend a "clean" install of 16.04.1 instead, especially since the transition from 14.04 to 16.04 involves going from SysVInit to systemd.

Comment: That's ok I already have 16.04

Comment: In that case, all you have to do is a normal update and you'll have 16.04.1.

Answer (score 4):

One part of your question wasn't addressed: "Do I have to upgrade my system?"

No, you do not.  14.04 will be supported until April 2019.

There are many reasons to upgrade, but you do not *have* to.

Comment: I actually have 16.04... Should make this clear in the question

Comment: @user3728501 Well that's an important detail that you should have included.

Comment: @edwinksl I have included it...